# Modify date in where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4

I am trying to find all bookings with an arrival date within the next 5 days. `arrival` is a date datatype. Here is my attempt:

```
@bookings = Booking.where("? > arrival-5.days", Time.now.to_date)
```

I've also tried:

```
@bookings = Booking.where("? > ?", Time.now.to_date, arrival-5.days)
```

but neither work. How could I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@bookings = Booking.where(["arrival <= ?", 5.days.from_now])
```

This would also pull in bookings from yesterday, but I'll let you figure that one out.

Comment: Yes I realise this but SO doesn't allow you to do it straight away - you have to wait for a number of minutes!!! Done it now though.